# Display only if a value is set, don't show if empty

Tags: php, html

Just like the title says. I'm trying to only show a line of code on a website if a value is set via a front end panel. The code which I currently have is like this:

For text field input:

```html
<li id="mh-estate_attribute" class="mh-estate__list__element">
  <strong>Energieträger:</strong>
  <a>
    <?php
      $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'energietraeger' );
      foreach($terms as $term) {
          echo $term->name;
      }
    ?>
  </a>
</li>
```

For number input:

```html
<li id="mh-estate_attribute" class="mh-estate__list__element">
  <strong>Baujahr (lt. Energieausweis):</strong>
  <a href="tel:<?php the_field('estate_attr_' . 'attribute_21', $myhome_estate->get_ID() ); ?>"><?php the_field('estate_attr_' . 'attribute_21', $myhome_estate->get_ID() ); ?></a>
</li>
```

So the problem is that an error code is shown on my website when no value is put in.

Comment: Hey I've added an answer for you, isn't helpful for you ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to only show a line of code on a website **if a value is set**

Try,

```
if(isset($variable)){
  //do what you want to do with not NULL variable
}
```

**OR** more specifically

```
if(!empty($variable){
 //do what you want to do with non-empty variable
}
```

Comment: `empty` could be better choice